# Gynaecology could use a synonym

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

At the moment, we have tag [gynaecology](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gynaecology) without any synonyms.

1. Why not have [gynecology](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gynecology) as a synonym?
2. Or, since [anaesthesia](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anaesthesia) is a [synonym](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1202/12704) for [anesthesia](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anesthesia), for the sake of consistency, why not have tag [gynecology](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gynecology) with synonym [gynaecology](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gynaecology)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implemented as suggested in the question.